# Bananagrams on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, games-toys

Is there a problem with playing [Bananagrams](http://www.bananagrams.com/games/bananagrams) on Shabbos because of Borer or any other reason?

Answer (score 7):

Playing Bananagrams isn't a borer issue since you choose pieces for immediate usage.  This is within the category of Derech Achila- normal consumption/usage.  Even at the beginning of the game when the pieces are separated, this is normal immediate usage.

Kesiva (writing) isn't a problem since there is nothing to unify the letters (like a frame).

In some circles, adults (over 13) refrain from games and other mundane actions on shabbos.

Comment: Any source or name of rov?

Comment: Another thing from what I have seen in Seforim the some circles seems to be Standardized Halacha they seem to say you must not and in Fact you should train your children past a ceartin age so if you could name an alternate source that the other circle relies on I would appreciate it

Comment: @SimchasTorah The _isur_ of adult people playing games on _shabas_ is mentioned in a mini-_t'shuva_ from Rav Moshe in the back of _Halachos of Muktzah_, in the section "questions the author asked Rav Moshe". (Sorry for the imprecision. This is based on memory.)

Comment: @SimchasTorah- Standardized halacha is Shulchan Aruch 301:2 (http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=412).  Many ared against it because shabbos should be reserved for holier matters.  Each situation needs to be judged individually.  If this person would not be playing, what would he be doing instead (besides witholding from his Oneg Shabbos)?

Comment: @ST- which halacha are you concerned about that you would like a source or Rav?  I understand I should bring sources, but it would help if you could be more specific in your concern.

Comment: Yup, sure is *derech achila*.